# Linq and nullable datetime

Tags: linq, datetime, nullable

I have method like below:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DateTime>> GetReportDates(int monthsBack)
    {
        return await _entities.view
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastUpdateDate)
            .Take(monthsBack)
            .Select(d => d.LastUpdateDate.Value)
            .Distinct()
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

My problem is that when I run my MVC page it stops on this method. I was waiting for few minutes with no success. There are about 600 rows in that view so it should not be a problem. Any suggestions what could be wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `ToListAsync()` with an immediate `await`? Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @NetMage Can you please post your solution?